# PolyBLEP: solving two part residual

Tags: aliasing, signal-synthesis, oscillator

The Polynomial Bandlimited Step (PolyBLEP) methodology involves approximating the *sinc()* function with a polynomial. The most basic polynomial to choose is a uni-polar triangular pulse as it is the linear approximation of the windowed *sinc()* pulse. Integrating it produces the bipolar integrated triangle which can be expressed as:

\begin{cases}0\,\textrm,&t<-1\\t^{2}/2+t+1/2,\,&-1\leq t\leq 0\\t-t^{2}/2+1/2,&0<t\leq 1\\1,\,&t>1\end{cases}

The PolyBLEP two part residual is then obtained by subtracting the [perfect step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) from the bipolar integrated triangle and converting again to bipolar.

[image]

Residual is then applied to the naive wave shape to offset the samples around the discontinuities, shifting them up or down to producing a smoothed waveform.

How are those polynomials and two part residual actually, step-by-step, 'derived'?

I tried to solve this two part residual through those bipolar integrated triangles and ended up to different result:

[image]

which results two part residual as:

```
-((|t|-1.0)(-|t|+1.0))
((|t|-1.0)(-|t|+1.0))
```

See: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xwqyghn8pb

Are my results OK/usable?